# 2010 Honda Fit Transmission Replacement

Tags: honda, transmission, automatic-transmission, replace

So I'm just looking for a sanity check ...

I was told today that my 2010 Honda Fit's transmission needs to be replaced at a cost of $4,400. At this point it's making a whoosh-whoosh noise that cycles higher relative to speed. The dealer says they don't know what the problem is, and they can't since it's a sealed unit. All they can do is replace.

1. Is this transmission serviceable, by anyone? Or is it just the dealer that will only replace?
2. If I just continue to drive without replacement, how can I expect it to fail eventually? Up in flames or slow and predictable?
3. Is it reasonable to have the transmission replaced by a second party?

Comment: You don't have to take it to the dealer. Any *good* transmission shop will tell you what the deal is and if they can service your tranny or not. They will ultimately be cheaper than the dealership and in most cases offer a better warranty. Get a second opinion, but ensure you are looking at a "good" shop before you do (do your homework; go online and read up on where ever you trust to give honest reviews). This is only my two cents worth, so take it as you will.